# Activity returns null instance

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm, using MainActivity as the Default activity. In the activity, i have created mainactivity variable globally and declared a static function to access the instance of Mainactivity. The reason for the static function is to access the MainActivity functions in the fragments.

Code snippet

```
private static MainActivity mainActivity;
public static MainActivity getMainActivity() {
    return mainActivity;
}
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mainActivity = this;
}
```

After terminate and reopen the application sometimes the getMainActivity() functions return null pointer exception. Could you please anyone figure out the cause of the issue?

Comment: `getMainActivity()` can never throw a NullPointerException, however, it can return null when it is called before the activity is created.

Comment: "The reason for the static function is to access the MainActivity functions in the fragments" - consider `((MainActivity)requireActivity())` instead assuming the fragments are attached to your main activity. Though even better if fragments have no idea where they are attached in and don't have dependencies to any activity.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare a static function to get activity's instance. You can simply call getActivity() method to get instance of current activity.

Replace

```
 getMainActivity()
```

with this

```
 getActivity()
```